# Pact: Solving PactMismatchesException

Tags: java, api, testing, consumer, pact

I'm trying to setup a contract test with Pact (so far only Consumer-side).
This is what my code looks like:

```
    @Pact(consumer = "Consumer")
    RequestResponsePact apiIsReachablePact(PactDslWithProvider builder) {
        return builder.given("api is reachable")
                .uponReceiving("load api")
                .method("GET")
                .path("/?format=json")
                .willRespondWith()
                .status(200)
                .headers(headers())
                .body(newJsonBody(object -> {
                    object.stringType("ip", "XYZ");
                }).build())
                .toPact();
    }

    @Test
    @PactTestFor(pactMethod = "apiIsReachablePact")
    public void apiIsReachable() throws IOException {

        //Given
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("https://api.ipify.org");

        //When
        HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);

        //Then
        assertEquals(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    }
```

I tried to make it as simple as possible, but I receive the following error:

```
au.com.dius.pact.consumer.PactMismatchesException: The following requests were not received:
    method: GET
    path: /?format=json
    query: {}
    headers: {}
    matchers: MatchingRules(rules={})
    generators: Generators(categories={})
    body: MISSING
    ...
```

Could anyone please help me along here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pact doesn't intercept your requests, so this call doesn't actually talk to the Pact mock server, hence why it was not received - it's going to the real API:

```java
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet("https://api.ipify.org");
```

You don't test against real API in Pact in the consumer test, you mock out the provider and test using the Pact Mock. It will then generate a contract that the provider can then use to verify your expectations:

It should be:

```java
    @Test
    @PactTestFor(pactMethod = "apiIsReachablePact")
    public void apiIsReachable(MockServer mockServer) throws IOException {

        //Given
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(mockServer.getUrl());

        //When
        HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpClientBuilder.create().build().execute(request);

        //Then
        assertEquals(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), HttpStatus.SC_OK);
    }
```

See this [example](https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/examples/java/consumer/junit/readme) and this [workshop](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-jvm-spring) for more.

Comment: Thank you! I finally understood how to build the consumer tests. Do you by any change also have an example of how to verify the provider with the API in the next step?

Comment: Have a look at the workshop, it goes through it all step by step